# Can sympy solve this ODE (y')**2 = y

Tags: sympy

Using Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux

Trying to see if sympy can solve $y'(x)^2 = y(x)$. The general solution can be easily solved by hand. But sympy gives `[]` for solution.

Did I type something wrong? Is there a trick to make sympy solve this?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> y = Function('y')
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> dsolve( Eq( Derivative(y(x),x)**2 , y(x) ),  y(x))
    []
```

Maple gives both the singular and general solution

```
ode:=( diff(y(x),x))^2=y(x);
dsolve( ode,y(x));
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica gives the general solution only

```
ode=(y'[x])^2==y[x]
DSolve[ode,y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can sympy solve this ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods implemented in SymPy focus on the ODEs in which the highest derivative of the unknown appears on its own, not inside of some function. Once the ODE is rewritten as `y'(x) = (+ or -) sqrt(y(x))`, SymPy solves it.

```
>>> dsolve(Eq(Derivative(y(x), x), sqrt(y(x))), y(x))
Eq(y(x), C1**2/4 + C1*x/2 + x**2/4)
>>> dsolve(Eq(Derivative(y(x), x), -sqrt(y(x))), y(x))
Eq(y(x), C1**2/4 - C1*x/2 + x**2/4)
```

This reduction can be done automatically with `solve`, starting with the original form of the equation:

```
rhs = solve(Eq(Derivative(y(x), x)**2, y(x)),  Derivative(y(x), x))
[dsolve(Eq(Derivative(y(x), x), r), y(x)) for r in rhs]
```